# How do you maximize a fragment (in Android) but not make it fullscreen?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I create a Navigation Drawer activity in Android.  When the user clicks on the menu items, each menu item opens up a fragment.

Each fragment is set to:

fragment.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    tools:context="com.go.tutorial.Fragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="hello fragment"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.go.tutorial.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout_for_fragment"
    android:background="@color/fragmentBackground">

</RelativeLayout>
```

However, the fragments expand to fit their contents instead of maximizing or becoming "fullscreen"?

This results in a shadow that borders the fragment and makes the design look ugly.

Is there any way to fix or work around this?

I don't want it to become true "fullscreen" per se.  But, I would like to maximize to the space of its parent activity.

I'm sure a lot of people would like fragments that automatically maximize to the full width and height of its parent activity right?

A feature like this should be built in since it seems like many would use it?

Comment: UI elements (including fragments) grow to the size of their parents.  If you're seeing a border, its because you have other UI elements onscreen at the sibling level or parent level.  Get rid of them and there won't be a border.  But if you want a more complete answer than this you'll need to post your entire layout.

Comment: Thank you.  I've updated the original question with the full fragment layout.  I just have a TextView on there at the moment?  I'm following this tutorial to learn about navigation drawer activities:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H4R-hz56oBA

Answer (score 0):

Replace you LinearLayout with FrameLayout , and make your fragment layout match parent .

Comment: Thank you, but that did not work?  The fragment is still not maximized.  I have 4 TextView objects in this fragment and after making the changes you specified, the 4 TextViews are now displayed on top of each other?

Comment: how they appear to you it is related to fragment layout design ,  not to FrameLayout in your activity .